# Do we have user control and hidden field in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In Asp.net , there is user control, which is an **ascx** page, and we can have hidden fields:

```
public partial class classA:System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Models.classB>
{
  //hidden field
  public string url
  {
    get{  ......   }
  }
}
```

But now i am using **razor** in asp.net mvc3 ,which is **cshtml** file. Do we have anything corresponding to that? How can i use hidden field now?

Comment: @DaveA:partial views have hidden fields?

Comment: Sure, you can make partials with hidden fields

Answer (score 1):

**MVC views do no have fields** like a Web Forms user control.

MVC views (partial views, too) get their data by passing an instance of a *Viewmodel* class to them. You can indicate the type of the viewmodel class with the `@model` directive (usually the first line in a view):

```
@model MyViewmodelClass

<span>@Model.MyClassProperty</span>
```

The viewmodel class itself could contain private fields like any class.

If you need variables to be used within the view itself, you can simply declare them within a razor code block and use them wwithin the view:

```
@{
  var privatevar = "value";
}
<span>@privatevar</span>
```

However, as a best practice, the view's responsibility in ASP.NET MVC should be limited to the display of the data and therefore not contain code unrelated to that.

Comment: I see, we extract the behind code in user control to viewModel, aiming at seperating views from data. Thanks for your adivce.

Comment: Where should i place ViewModel, just in the same folder of Models?

Comment: For very simple apps, a Model may be used as Viewmodel. However, I usually have only Viewmodels in my MVC project, have the controller call the services layer and populate the viewmodels to send to the view. Most of the time, this means one viewmodel for each view. See also one of the excellent articles of Jimmy Bogard for further reading: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/24/how-we-do-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

While working with razor it is essential to have basic HTML knowledge as you need to write some html and there is no and Drag and Drop to add controls on the page. 
MVC have introduced Partial Views which can be said a alternate/replacement to User Control.
You can create a PartialView by selecting Checkbox stating "Create Partial View" in View Creation Dialog. Secondly In MVC it is not difficult to create partial view mannual as well.
As you are using Razor, just set `Layout = null;` at the top of your view and it will be treated as partial view. Secondly you can easily make any field as hidden using `display` property under Style attribute.

Happy Coding :)